# Is Google adsense available for localhost?

Tags: localhost, adsense

Is it possible to run google adsense ads on a local server as a try out for a example application?
I want to implement Google adsense ads in my web application which is running on a localost befor implementing in a live website.
If possible then please suggest me the way.

Thank you.

Comment: (data-adtest="on") not works for me.
[you can look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73498830/2123797)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes it is possible (as of 2015). There is a special parameter, to use Adsense on Localhost without risks.

Today the AdSense code is different. If you want to add the adtest-parameter use `data-adtest="on"` within an ins block. Here is an example code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- XYZ 336 x 280 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 data-adtest="on"
 data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

**Found this on Google AdManager Help:**

It shows a basic tutorial on how to achieve this.

[Test Ad Exchange tags without charging advertisers or recording clicks and impressions](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/4599514?hl=en)

> Add the google_adtest = on; parameter to your ad tag to specify that this is a test implementation. Make sure you set this parameter to "on" to ensure that clicks and impressions aren't recorded and advertisers aren't charged. The default value is "off".

Comment: Is this advice still valid today? Tested the code (placed correct pub id and slot id) but it doesn't work - I only see a white space where ads should be displayed.

Comment: I also just see white space. However you can select a different color to display in the AdSense dashboard in the ad settings under `Backup ads`. This at least shows exactly where the ad will be displayed.

Comment: using the above code my ads is not displayed in localhost it's displayed blank space. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: i tried using above code mentioned by you it came first time in localhost but  next time i can't see add, it shows blank space

Comment: @IvanGabriele Next time just update the answer instead of being passive aggressive :)

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Indeed you're correct, I should have been more participative !

Comment: Didn't work for me too. It just leaves the empty space. Tried both `data-adtest` and `data-ad-test`.

Comment: This should not be marked as solution anymore as it simply does not work. The Google Chrome inspector says `failed to load resource, 403`, so a super admin should mark this question as open again with the note: Solution required for 2019!

Comment: If this answer didn't work for you: check out my answer below (it is working for me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694852/10128619

Answer (score 16):

After lots of trials and errors, here is what I've found out. At least, those were my results.

It seems that `adsbygoogle.js` will not render ads on `localhost`. You'll probably will get something like the following:

[image]

So, the first thing you need to do is to set up a local custom domain for your `localhost`.

Here is what I do on Windows:

- Run NotePad as Admnistrator.
- Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
- Add your custom domain to the list

[image]

[image]

Then you should be able to access your `localhost` by hitting `dev.mydomain.com`

After you've set up your local domain, you should go to your **AdSense account and add it as a subdomain under the main domain** of your registered website.

[image]

From the tests I've run. It seems that AdSense will not render real nor test ads if the domain/subdomain has not been added to your AdSense account.

In this example, I've added the main domain without the `www` and I've added two subdomains. One is the `www.` variation and the other one is the `dev.` that I've just added to my `localhost`.

Then you can render it on your code, just like you would on a real add and use the `data-adtest` flag set to `on` to run your tests.

```
<ins className="adsbygoogle"
  style={{display:"inline-block", width:"100%", height: "100%"}}
  data-ad-client={AD_SENSE_ACCOUNT}
  data-ad-slot={AD_SENSE_SLOT}
  data-adtest={ON_DEV ? "on" : "off"}
>
</ins>
```

I have an `ON_DEV` flag that automatically sets it to `on`, whenever I'm on my `dev.` domain.

**EXTRA**

This is out of the scope of this question, but is necessary for everything to work.

You also need to push it to the `adsbygoogle` array. This is how I do it in React.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
},[]);
```

And of course, you need the `adsense` `<script/>` tag on your `index.html` as well.

```
<script data-ad-client="XXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly:  It is no  problem, that test.mydomain.com cannot be resolved  by public DNS?  Will this also work with fifferent domain names? So if I have called my host mydomain.test I could add this to my Adsense account  set the test flag and it should work?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need a valid registered/verified domain on your AdSense account. And then you can add subdomain variations of that domain. But I don't think you can add different domain names. Each one would need to be verified. Like `mydomain.com` is a different domain than `mydomain.test`.

Comment: Thank you, this is my answer to what I looking for. I work fine

Comment: As of Feb 2023, you can no longer add subdomains in AdSense, so that no longer works.

Answer (score 9):

I wasn't able to get the ads to show up using `data-adtest="on"` in localhost either. Since there was still an empty div, as a quick work around I added a border to the styles so it looks like `display: inline-block; border: 1px solid green;`. I was only concerned about placement and how it would interact with my layout and not so much what the ad looked like, so this allowed me to see the dimensions of the ad and make any layout adjustments accordingly.

Comment: yeah same, and just to be safe I added   `min-height: 10vh;    min-width: 50vw; `
so that chrome won't catch an empty ad which crashes the page.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to make Adsense ads work on localhost by following the next steps:

**1) Add ads.txt file in root of** `myDomain`

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7532444?hl=en-GB

The file should be available for `GET at myDomain.com/ads.txt`

(I am not sure if the ads would work without this step)

**2) Edit the hosts system file**:

in Linux and macOS you can find it at `/etc/hosts`

There add a line like this `127.0.0.1 mylocalstuff.myDomain.com`

run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

A browser restart might also be needed.

Without this step you will probably get a `403`

**3) Use the `data-adtest="on"`** in the `ins` tag so the impressions are not affected.

Access `mylocalstuff.myDomain.com` in the browser (or `mylocalstuff.myDomain.com<:PORT_NUMBER>` if your local server is available at a port number different than 80).

The steps where inspired from sources:

https://medium.com/@jeffersonlicet/testing-ads-on-localhost-300215b415d6

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389120/1979861

Note: pay also attention to the space for ads (styles). If that is too restricted by some width or height you can get an error and you will see a blanc space.

Answer (score 4):

You can put this as the first line of the code:

```
google_adtest = "on";
```

test-adsense-ads-on-your-site

Note that you must put the semicolon (`;`) at the end of this line.

Once you add this line to the code, for the adsense unit, it will be displayed as a test unit and its impressions won’t be counted.

Very Important Note - Once you are satisfied with the adsense unit, don't forget to remove this line from the code.

Check out this link: 
http://www.hacktrix.com/2-ways-to-safely-test-google-adsense-ads-on-your-site

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get ads working in localhost by adding an entry into my `hosts` file.

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Then add the following at the end of the file:

```
127.0.0.1 local.your-page.com
```

You can now reach your localhost by going to http://local.your-page.com:3000
Note that you still need to add the port (in this example `:3000`)

Also, when working with ads it's always good to do your tests **in incognito and without any browser extension** (they may be blocking the ads)