# Is it possible to test Google AutoAds in a demo or localhost environment?

Tags: adsense

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864860/is-google-adsense-available-for-localhost?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), I would like to test Google Adsense in a page to see how it impacts layout and performance, etc. before go-live.  I would like to do this on https://localhost and on a demo site.  However, my customer is using AutoAds, with markup that looks like this:

```
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1234567890",
            enable_page_level_ads: true,
            google_adtest: "on" //This doesn't seem to work?
        });
    </script>
```

Is there a way to test AutoAds on localhost and non-production sites?  Related, is there documentation for google_adtest?

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no ... more like no :) I still recommend you try.

So basically Auto Ads don't run right away, because Google needs time to analyze not only ur site's content, but also structure.

So because `localhost` is not a public domain, google structure crawler can't see ur site... However I do see live google ads on my localhost ... the non-auto- ads... Regular fixed size ads.

Also, auto ads is [not very profitable](https://www.adsenseninja.com/adsense-auto-ads-review/)