# why doesn't Google Ads doesn't shows up?

Tags: reactjs, google-ads-api

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Bling as GPT} from "react-gpt";

function Ads() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || [];
    window.adsbygoogle.push({});
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <ins className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{display:"block", width:"250px"}}
        data-ad-format="fluid"
        data-ad-layout-key="-fb+5w+4e-db+86"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-1716395586958019"
        data-ad-slot="9360082050"
        data-adtest="on">
      </ins>

    </>
  )
}

// result of HTML after adding the above code. But I think data-ad-status is unfilled but don't know why.
<ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-layout-key="-fb+5w+4e-db+86" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1716395586958019" data-ad-slot="9360082050" data-adtest="on" style="display: block; width: 250px; height: 315px;" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled">
        <div id="aswift_1_host" tabindex="0" title="Advertisement" aria-label="Advertisement" style="border: none; height: 315px; width: 250px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; display: inline-block;">
          <iframe id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:250px;height:315px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" width="250" height="315" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-1716395586958019&amp;output=html&amp;h=315&amp;slotname=9360082050&amp;adk=179383159&amp;adf=4280140434&amp;pi=t.ma~as.9360082050&amp;w=250&amp;lmt=1686243940&amp;rafmt=11&amp;format=250x315&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&amp;adtest=on&amp;wgl=1&amp;uach=WyJXaW5kb3dzIiwiMTUuMC4wIiwieDg2IiwiIiwiMTE0LjAuNTczNS45MCIsW10sMCxudWxsLCI2NCIsW1siTm90LkEvQnJhbmQiLCI4LjAuMC4wIl0sWyJDaHJvbWl1bSIsIjExNC4wLjU3MzUuOTAiXSxbIkdvb2dsZSBDaHJvbWUiLCIxMTQuMC41NzM1LjkwIl1dLDBd&amp;dt=1686243940235&amp;bpp=18&amp;bdt=833&amp;idt=119&amp;shv=r20230606&amp;mjsv=m202306050101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3D0131efc224260eb6-22fb51662ce000b1%3AT%3D1686054747%3ART%3D1686243870%3AS%3DALNI_Mau56qS_H-iE3bKsxmOr1TCP2_z-A&amp;gpic=UID%3D00000c4416918412%3AT%3D1686054747%3ART%3D1686243870%3AS%3DALNI_MY2nh_dm0Uime-_txjeT8hChnoM8w&amp;prev_fmts=0x0&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=1903045135563&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=725767110.1686051615&amp;ga_sid=1686243940&amp;ga_hid=1689683430&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=60&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=900&amp;u_w=1440&amp;u_ah=852&amp;u_aw=1440&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=2&amp;dmc=8&amp;adx=53&amp;ady=1021&amp;biw=1423&amp;bih=781&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=527&amp;eid=44759837%2C44759875%2C44759926%2C31075127%2C44788441%2C31067147&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=4370208828608287&amp;tmod=82592742&amp;uas=0&amp;nvt=2&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1440%2C0%2C1440%2C852%2C1440%2C781&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7C%7CeE%7C&amp;abl=CS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=31&amp;td=1&amp;ifi=2&amp;uci=a!2&amp;fsb=1&amp;xpc=2FhlrG9d3m&amp;p=http%3A//localhost%3A3000&amp;dtd=137" data-google-container-id="a!2" data-load-complete="true">
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </ins>
```

I'm using the above code to showcase the ads in React project. Although there is no error, ads never appear on localhost. Secondly, is it possible to show ads on local host environments and I have no ad blocker installed on my computer. I'm following the following article
https://www.tutorialsbuddy.com/embed-google-adsense-code-in-react-component

After inspecting the above is the HTML result.

Comment: Do you have an ADS blocker turned on by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have this piece of code in the Head tag:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-123456789" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For localhost you need to add this parameter in the:

```
<ins>
        style={{display:"block", width:"250px"}}
        data-ad-format="fluid"
        data-ad-layout-key="-fb+5w+4e-db+86"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-1716395586958019"
        data-ad-slot="9360082050">
        data-adtest="on" // This paramter for localhost 
</ins>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864860/is-google-adsense-available-for-localhost) for a better explanation.

Comment: Well, I have tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Has your site been approved by google? I thought they had to review it before ads were shown?

Comment: Well, I have not hosted this site right now and I'm just building it in my local environment.